# Explain how this limit is = 1?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{\frac{h}{1+h}}{h}=1$$

Im unsure how this is 1, as would it not be undefined at h = 0?

Comment: When does $h=0$? Remember $h\to 0^+$ means getting arbitrarily close to $0$ but not equal to zero.

Comment: My bad, I'm computing this by substituting 0 in for h.

Comment: as a more general comment, $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=f(a)$ only when $f$ is continuous at $a$ (and $a$ is an accumulation point of the domain of $f$). In this case, the function is undefined at $a=0$ and thus not continuous. But when $h\neq 0$, algebra saves the day-you can rewrite the function as a continuous function and thus use the desired substitution.

Answer (score 3):

If $h$ approaches to zero by the right then $h\neq 0$, so we can do this

$$\require{cancel}\frac{\frac{h}{1+h}}{h}=\frac{\cancel{h}}{1+h}\cdot\frac1{\cancel{h}}=\frac1{1+h}$$

Hence

$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{\frac{h}{1+h}}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac1{1+h}=1$$

Comment: That explains it perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\frac h{1+h}}h=\frac1{1+h}\xrightarrow[h\to0]{}1$$